# Full path is added into project file when adding metadata references via Roslyn

Tags: c#, roslyn

I'm trying to copy all metadata references from one project into another via Roslyn.

```
var updatedProject = destinationProject.AddMetadataReferences(sourceProject.MetadataReferences);
msWorkSpace.TryApplyChanges(updatedProject.Solution)
```

The references are copied without problems but the full path to the assembly is added into the project file:

```
<Reference Include="C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.5.2\System.Numerics.dll" />
```

Is there some option to add them via Roslyn (I don't want to manually edit csproj file) in this way?

```
<Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a bug. Please file the bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn).

Comment: @mpietrzyk: did you file a bug by chance?

Comment: Ah, I see you filed [this bug](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/5959). Thanks!